# Android intent filter custom data scheme doesn't allow queryIntentActivities

Tags: android, android-intent, filter

I'm trying to create a custom intent for my application so I can extend it by searching for installed packages that support my scheme and using them, essentially, as plugins. I have the following in my manifest

```
<activity android:name=".myMagicActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mydomain.action.MYMAGICTHING"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="mymagicthing" android:host="mydomain.com"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My test application runs fine and I can start the intent, see the data as expected. However, if I try to test for the existence of the intent first it will fail. *Always*.

I'm using the following code to check

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);

    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

which is from the [Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html) The results are as follows:

```
02-28 21:56:54.186: V/IntentResolver(150): Resolving type null scheme null of intent Intent { act=com.mydomain.action.MYMAGICTHING flg=0x8 }
02-28 21:56:54.186: V/IntentResolver(150): Action list: null
02-28 21:56:54.186: D/INTENT(17088): Intent MISSING
02-28 21:56:54.186: V/IntentResolver(150): Final result list:
```

If I remove the data element from the manifest, the detection of the intent works perfectly, but obviously no data is passed to the intent as it doesn't actually start.

```
02-28 22:11:14.886: V/IntentResolver(150): Resolving type null scheme null of intent Intent { act=com.mydomain.action.MYMAGICTHING flg=0x8 }
02-28 22:11:14.886: V/IntentResolver(150): Action list: [ActivityIntentInfo{415df398 com.mydomain.myMagicActivity}]
02-28 22:11:14.886: V/IntentResolver(150): Matching against filter ActivityIntentInfo{415df398 com.mydomain.myMagicActivity}
02-28 22:11:14.886: V/IntentResolver(150):   Filter matched!  match=0x108000
02-28 22:11:14.886: V/IntentResolver(150): Final result list:
02-28 22:11:14.886: D/INTENT(17088): found intent
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: did you tried to set data to intent `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mymagicthing://mydomain.com"));` before you used it `in queryIntentActivities`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be many reasons for this

**Possible reason 1 - DATA absent/incorrect in intent object:**

As per the "[Intent and Intent Filter developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)" for intent resolution, one must pass the data test, part of which says:

> "An Intent object that contains neither a URI nor a data type passes
>   the test only if the filter likewise does not specify any URIs or data
>   types."

In other words, here your intent filter has a 'DATA' section which contains a URI defined by a scheme and host but the intent object you created to test your application doesn't have a 'DATA' section (or has one which is not the same as the filter) and that is why the intent resolution fails.

**Possible reason 2 - DATA TYPE not mentioned in intent object and filter:**

Does your app use a URI scheme like mailto: or tel:? If not (clearly you use mymagicthing), you need to specify a DATA TYPE in the filter or the resolution will fail! Reference:

> An Intent object that contains a URI but no data type (and a type
>   cannot be inferred from the URI) passes the test only if its URI
>   matches a URI in the filter and the filter likewise does not specify a
>   type. This will be the case only for URIs like mailto: and tel: that
>   do not refer to actual data.

**Possible solution:**

So if you have a custom URI, you must specify a DATA TYPE along with the URI (scheme, host etc) Then, in your test code, create an intent with DATA(both URI and TYPE) that matches with the DATA in the intent filter

> An Intent object that contains both a URI and a data type (or a data
>   type can be inferred from the URI) passes the data type part of the
>   test only if its type matches a type listed in the filter. It passes
>   the URI part of the test either if its URI matches a URI in the filter
>   or if it has a content: or file: URI and the filter does not specify a
>   URI. In other words, a component is presumed to support content: and
>   file: data if its filter lists only a data type.

Example: define a MIME type for your data like

```
 <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg">
```

for more examples refer to the "[Intent and Intent Filter developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)"

Comment: Thank you, after staring at it for a number of hours and then coming back to your answer I see my error -